# How to make my spider's leg move in XNA

Tags: xna, 3d, blender, maya, 3d-modelling

I've done a 3D spider model in Blender, and currently I can export it as a .x(direct X) file and import this .x file into XNA gamestudio and make it shown there as a static model.

Now this project is coming to the final stage, that is, we need to make one of its legs move back and forth in the XNA, however,it only needs to move back and forth, so no keyboard response is required.

We already successfully made one leg of the spider in the Blender has bones and armature and ik constraint, so in Blender, I can drag the leg to move. But now we are really stuck on how to get this move automatically in XNA, we tried exporting it as .x file the same way as before, but this time it won't even show in XNA.

It would be really great if you could give us a little help here, or maybe refer us to some tutorials on how to animate Blender model in XNA, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a pretty good thread in the XNA forums that talks about animating models
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/53155/322140.aspx